org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog 175 log - Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches
I am get error "org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog 175 log - Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches for web application [ROOT] java.lang.ClassCastExcepti
on: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
this is stack info:
org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog 175 log - Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches for web application [ROOT] java.lang.ClassCastExcepti
on: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearCache(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2194) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1567) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1497) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:442) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1445) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1001) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1445) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1001) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:380) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar!/:9.0.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:309) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at me.zhengjie.AppRun.main(AppRun.java:38) [classes!/:1.5]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [eladmin-system.jar.202404160913:1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [eladmin-system.jar.202404160913:1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [eladmin-system.jar.202404160913:1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [eladmin-system.jar.202404160913:1.5]

when we want to deplay in product environment, we find  this error.but when we deplay in test environmnet ,It's no any ereor.i don't know why,so anyone can help me?

Does this answer your question? ClassCastException when stopping Tomcat 10 inside Eclipse

I get it, my application.yml has some error. It not has a configuration,when start project,spring not print debug log, and we can't find really reason . so this error in fact valueless.
why spring not print really reason.beacuse spring default deug is false;
enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
